# SwipeItem and TapGestureRecognizer don't call Command

Tags: c#, .net, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I have added commands on StackLayout in CollectionView, but the commands are not calling. What is wrong? I used this [tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F31e4siUvV4&list=PLprnOV9ZLFnt8mtFGpLGDMCpPVajLzq22&index=11) to learn how to bind a command in CollectionView like this:

```cs
<SwipeView.RightItems>
     <SwipeItems>
         <SwipeItem Text="Delete" Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ProductPageViewModel}}, Path="ProductTappedDeleteCommand"}", CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
          </SwipeItem>
     </SwipeItems>
</SwipeView.RightItems>
```

In the video, this code works correctly. I tried it this way - SwipeItem and TapGestureRecognizer don't call the command. I've been trying to fix this error for 2 days, and I can't do it.

XAML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ColorLab.Pages.UserDiagnosticPage"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:ColorLab.Types"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ColorLab.ViewModels"
             Title="UserDiagnosticPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <RefreshView x:DataType="local:UserDiagnosticViewModel"
                     Command="{Binding LoadDiagnosticCommand}"
                     IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy}">
            <Grid>
                <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding combinedUdDatas}">
                    <CollectionView.EmptyView>
                    ...
                    </CollectionView.EmptyView>

                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:CombinedUdData">
                            <StackLayout Padding="2">
                                <SwipeView>
                                    <SwipeView.RightItems>
                                        <SwipeItem Text="Delete" Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:UserDiagnosticViewModel}}, Path=UdTappedDeleteCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource DangerButton}"/>
                                        <SwipeItem Text="Cancel" IsDestructive="True" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}"/>
                                    </SwipeView.RightItems>

                                    <Grid Padding="10" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="215" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="45" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="35" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding UserDiagnostic.SessionDate}" FontSize="18" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="Цвет:" FontSize="16" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"/>
                                        <BoxView Grid.Column="2" Color="{Binding UdMauiColor[0].OriginalColor}"/>
                                        <Image Source="open_object.png" Grid.Column="3" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30">
                                            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                                <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:UserDiagnosticViewModel}}, Path=UdDiagnosticTappedCommand}"
                                                                      CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
                                                </TapGestureRecognizer>
                                            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                        </Image>
                                    </Grid>
                                </SwipeView>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
            </Grid>
        </RefreshView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

.cs file for this page:

```cs
using ColorLab.ViewModels;

namespace ColorLab.Pages;

public partial class UserDiagnosticPage : ContentPage
{
    UserDiagnosticViewModel _userDiagnosticViewModel;

    public UserDiagnosticPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _userDiagnosticViewModel = new(Navigation);
        this.BindingContext = _userDiagnosticViewModel;
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        _userDiagnosticViewModel.OnAppering();
    }
}
```

In UserDiagnosticViewModel i tried different ways for binding commands:

```cs
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using ColorLab.Types;
using ColorLab.Pages;

namespace ColorLab.ViewModels
{
    public partial class UserDiagnosticViewModel : BaseUdViewModel
    {

        public ObservableCollection<Types.CombinedUdData> combinedUdDatas { get; }

        public ICommand UdTappedDeleteCommand { get; }

        public UserDiagnosticViewModel(INavigation navigation)
        {
            combinedUdDatas = new();
            Navigation = navigation;
            UdTappedDeleteCommand = new RelayCommand<Types.CombinedUdData>(UdTappedDelete);
        }

        public void OnAppering()
        {
            IsBusy = true;
        }

        [ICommand]
        private async Task LoadDiagnostic()
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            try
            {
                //...
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        }

        private async void UdTappedDelete(Types.CombinedUdData data)
        {
            if (data == null)
                return;
            await App.DiagnosticHistoryService.RemoveUserDiagnosticAsync(data.UserDiagnostic.Id);
            await LoadDiagnostic();
            OnAppering();
        }

        private async void UdDiagnosticTapped(Types.CombinedUdData data)
        {
            if (data == null)
                return;
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new ViewDiagnosticPage(data));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two `SwipeItem` but you are missing `<SwipeItems>` in your xaml. Your Swipe should look like this:

```xml
<SwipeView.RightItems>
    <SwipeItems>
        <SwipeItem
            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource DangerButton}"
            Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:UserDiagnosticViewModel}}, Path=UdTappedDeleteCommand}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
            Text="Delete" />
        <SwipeItem
            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
            IsDestructive="True"
            Text="Cancel" />
    </SwipeItems>
</SwipeView.RightItems>
```

Comment: Thanks. Now i got the error, because i made a crooked sqlite table. xD

Comment: I am confused. This was the reason why you couldn't get to the command. Why is this not the right answer? Your commands and everything else in the VM worked fine with some loving and caring.

Comment: Sorry about that. It's just not the only problem.

Comment: Technically, the issue was two-fold, it seems. One thing was the `<SwipeItems>` - good catch - and the other was that the commands just weren't correctly set up, one was even completely missing. Happy to read that the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Your commands are not set up correctly.

- First of all, there is no `[ICommand]` source generator, you probably mean `[RelayCommand]`
- Secondly, it's better to set up your different commands in the same way
- Thirdly, there is no `UdDiagnosticTappedCommand`
- Lastly, you should avoid `async void` method signatures at all times. The only exception are event handlers, which cannot be of type `Task`.

**Note:** Make sure to use the correct Community Toolkit. You should be using the [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/) for the `[RelayCommand]` and not the Microsoft Toolkit, which is deprecated.

Change your ViewModel like this:

```cs
namespace ColorLab.ViewModels
{
    public partial class UserDiagnosticViewModel : BaseUdViewModel
    {

        public ObservableCollection<Types.CombinedUdData> combinedUdDatas { get; }

        public UserDiagnosticViewModel(INavigation navigation)
        {
            combinedUdDatas = new();
            Navigation = navigation;
        }

        public void OnAppering()
        {
            IsBusy = true;
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        private async Task LoadDiagnostic()
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            try
            {
                //...
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        private async Task UdTappedDelete(Types.CombinedUdData data)
        {
            if (data == null)
                return;
            await App.DiagnosticHistoryService.RemoveUserDiagnosticAsync(data.UserDiagnostic.Id);
            await LoadDiagnostic();
            OnAppering();
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        private async Task UdDiagnosticTapped(Types.CombinedUdData data)
        {
            if (data == null)
                return;
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new ViewDiagnosticPage(data));
        }
    }
}
```

In your XAML, you should add the `x:DataType` attribute to the root of the page to enable compiled bindings, this will help you finding binding issues faster, because binding issues will emit compiler errors for you:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ColorLab.Pages.UserDiagnosticPage"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:ColorLab.Types"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ColorLab.ViewModels"
             x:DataType="local:UserDiagnosticViewModel"
             Title="UserDiagnosticPage">

    <!-- ... -->

</ContentPage>
```

Last, but not least, you're mixing UI and Business Logic and aren't strictly following the MVVM pattern. For example, `OnAppearing()` is something that the ViewModel shouldn't know about, that's UI-related only. Your ViewModel shouldn't know about Pages and Views, either. You may want to rethink that part of the design.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working for SwipeItem. I think this is a problem with the interface.

Comment: I missed that there was a `<SwipeItems>` missing in the XAML. You should set up your commands properly, anyway.